# Media queries versus other methods / Universal Mobile support

Tags: css, mobile, cross-browser

I am building a mobile site and have looked into media queries but don't really like the lack of support. I'm really wondering what methods or approaches are commonly recommended.

On our site we are using head.js (http://headjs.com/) which adds classes into the  tag about the client, notably: browser, width and supported features. What do people think about using this javascript method as a better supported way of handling different users and changing the design layout accordingly.

I do feel that perhaps this JS approach is used as our main method but that it might be worth using a number of others a fallbacks. Here is perhaps a chain of support.

1st: All universal styles plus layout for narrowest device window.
2nd: Use some method of CSS targetting to add a desktop style sheet if desktop viewing is assumed, possibly media=screen

After this we are handling the lowest and the highest denominator.

Finally: Use the styles (width etc) created by the javascript to fine tune the design for different layouts.

Thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by lack of support? I think you'll find media queries are better supported on mobile devices than Javascript.

Comment: @roryf That may be the case but they aren't 100% supported (not just talking Android and iPhone here) and I am trying to support as many different devices as possible so trying to combine a number of methods together to hit as much as possible.

Comment: Oh and I'm also trying to change the layout depending on widths of desktop views and have it work in IE / old browsers etc.